# Pattern check returning false javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I am trying to validate if a string I entered matches the date format 'MM/yyyy'

Below is a sample of the code I am using for the same:

```
var date='05/2016'
var patt= new RegExp('^((0[1-9])|(1[0-2])|[1-9])\/(\d{4})$');
patt.test(date);
```

However the above code is returning false.

I tried running it with the regex checker:
https://regex101.com/

The pattern seems to be working fine.

Could someone please let me know what is missing.
https://jsfiddle.net/ymj6o8La/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to escape the string that is passed to RegExp (the backslashes).

```
var patt= new RegExp('^((0[1-9])|(1[0-2])|[1-9])\\/(\\d{4})$');
```

Even better, in your case, it's not dynamic, so you should use the literal RegExp instead

```
var patt = /^((0[1-9])|(1[0-2])|[1-9])\/(\d{4})$/
```

Answer (score 0):

You should escape your backslashes. To represent `\d` or even `\`  you should another backslash behind it `(e.g: \\)` :

```js
var date = '05/2016'
var patt = new RegExp('^((0[1-9])|(1[0-2])|[1-9])\\/(\\d{4})$');
console.log(patt.test(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a pattern like this

```
patt= /^((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/(\d{4})$/;
```